# Average radius of curvature of set of points on a road?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, curvature, angle, spline

I have a set of points (lat, lng) on a serpentine road. What would be a good way to calculate average radius of curvature of the road?

Also even without considering (lat, lng) points, just on a 2D surface, assuming there are lots of points (xi, yi) which can be part of a 2D road, what is the best way to calculate 
1 - an overall curvature
2 - individual curvatures of each of the convex/concave sections.

One can partition by calculating the inflection points, and then may be use the formula given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/133638/how-does-this-equation-to-find-the-radius-from-3-points-actually-work) but I was wondering any other better way of doing this. Since it is possible to have a convex section which is very complicated and just taking 3 points may not give the full picture.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: What do you call "an overall curvature" ? And as you say yourself, convex sections can be "complicated" so what would an "individual" curvature mean ?

Comment: By individual curvature I mean if we take 3 points at a time and find a curvature for those and then take the next three and so on.

Comment: Why are you asking how to compute the individual curvatures if you already know ?

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this, I would use a smooth interpolating curve with at least $G_2$ continuity. The cubic spline is a good candidate.

Then you can establish the analytical expression of the curvature for every piece of the spline and draw a plot with arbitrary sampling. You will probably want to plot the curvature as a function of the curvilinear abscissa (intrinsic curve equation).

You can obtain the curvilinear abscissas by numerical integration, and at the same time, integrate the (absolute) curvature to get an average.

Answer (score 0):

The proper definition of curvature of a smooth curve involves the second derivative, The wikipedia [curvature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature) page has all the formulas. With those you can calculate the curvature at any point, the total curvature and the average curvature (the latter two will be integrals).

If the known points on your curve are close enough together (particularly where the curvature is large) you can calculate the derivatives and integrals numerically.